# Edit all rows for one column in a GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I would like to be able to bulk edit all the rows for one column using a GridView control. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to update all rows with same value then show proper control(textbox/dropdown/checkbox/radio) in column header 
else
show the grid column in edit mode instead of label.

See following:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/BulkEditGridView.aspx

Comment: Edited answer, see the sample link.

Comment: I ended up using a similar approach to this control by inheriting from GridView and overriding the CreateRow event.

Answer (score 0):

I guess u know this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972948.aspx

Comment: Yes, thanks for the answer. That only allows you to edit one row at a time. I would like to edit all the rows for one column.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best, but an option is to set the primary key of your table as the DataKey of the GridView then iterate the grid and use the datakey and the edited value to update the DB. Here is an example.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID">
    <Columns>.....


foreach (var item in GridView1.Items)
  {
    var id = (Guid)GridView1.DataKeys[item.DataItemIndex].Value;
    var txt= item.FindControl("AmountTextBox") as Textbox;

    if (cb != null && id.HasValue)
      UpdateRow(id.Value, txt.Text);
  }
```